# Cannot run master locally because my EF Code First Migrations out of sync

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am running into a problem with EF6 code first migrations.

When I am in a lower sub branch where I am making my dev changes for new things to go out, I have migrations in that branch and my database has those changes.

When I switch to my master branch (i do not want to merge) and i try to run it locally, my migrations exist in my database but not in that branch of code.

I am trying to make a bug fix to go out to production from the master branch and do not want to run any new migrations but it tells me:

> The model backing the 'DummyDBContext' context has changed since the
>   database was created.

How can i get around this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've really got two problems here.

1. The migrations history that is stored in your database (in the _MigrationHistory table) is out of sync with the migrations that you've got on the master branch. This is what's causing the `InvalidOperationException` to be thrown.
2. The actual database schema is now out of sync with the way EF is understanding your schema based on the migrations that exist in the master branch. Based on your current code (in master), the schema should really look like it did before you switched to the subBranch and made changes.

The simplest way out of this is to just roll back the 'subBranch' migration before switching back to master (By calling `Update-Database -TargetMigration [NameOfPreviousMigration]`). The downside is that you're going to have to re-run the migration any time you switch back to the subBranch.

Otherwise, the way around this is going to entail:

1. Manually deleting the migration history from the _MigrationHistory table.
2. Rolling back any changes that were made to the database schema by either setting the `DbInitializer` to `DropCreate` (which will delete all the data in your DB, so watch out w/ this one) or manually undoing any changes made to the schema by the migration. 
   And if you do go this route, you're going to need to re-run the migration from scratch when you switch back to subBranch either way.

Good Luck ;)